# Is there a design pattern for this usage?

Tags: design-patterns, rust

(Not necessarily restricted to Rust, it happens to be the tech stack I'm working with)

My use case is the following: users would like to measure external variables (eg. amperage, temperature, anything numerical) and pipe that measurement into a public API I am building. Let's say that users will perform their measurement via some `Device` and feed that input into my `Analyser`. The user will repeatedly measure and feed the measurement into my Analyser; the analyser generates an `AnalyserOutput` which the user uses as feedback for their device. High-level pseudocode looks like this:

```
// User inits their device. This can be anything the user wishes to use
let device = TemperatureGauge::Device::new();

// Init analyser (my public API)
let analyser = Analyser::new();

loop {
   // read some value
   let read_val: f64 = device.read();
   
   // problem: 
   // calculate feedback immediately after read
   // if there was a significant delay between these
   // calls eg. I inserted a thread::sleep(1000)
   // then the output generated would be inaccurate. How can
   // I enforce that there is nothing between these two
   // invocations?
   let output_feedback = analyser.next(read_val);

   // set some external variable via device based on feedback
   device.set(read_val + output_feedback);

   thread::sleep(1);
}
```

Here is the problem: the `analyser.read(read_val)` method is dependent on the time at which the current `read_val` was read and the time in which the previous `read_val` was read at. This means that I need the user to call `.next()` immediately after their `.read()` invocations.

I'm struggling with designing an API to enforce this constraint. I have no control over what and how the user is measuring. It could be some driver or it could be a simple calculation. Now, I'm stuck with *assuming* that the user has invoked my API under the correct circumstances.

Are there design patterns that can help me enforce this constraint: immediately following some-kind of a user 'read' invocation is an `analyser.read()` invocation?

Comment: Why not just take a closure as parameter for the `next` method, like: `analyser.next(|| device.read())` in which case the analyser is responsible for actually triggering the actual read.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add a timestamp to each measurement, or, to put it alternatively, to make time a part of your measurement. After all, it seems that your analyzer is dependent on it as much as the rest of the measurement.

Comment: @BlackBeans I think this might be the best solution. I initially avoided this because I wanted to abstract the time away from the user. But that doesn't seem to make sense anymore since the time is actually part of the measurement.

Answer (score 2):

*Some* latency is unavoidable. The processor takes time to move data. The data from the sensor may have passed through some kind of buffer/queue before the processor got it. Additionally, `Device::read()` and `Device::set()` might be implemented in some unfortunately inefficient way.

In your situation, where you're writing a library, not controlling the overall program *and the hardware it runs on*, the best you can do is to clearly document that the latency between `read()`, `next()`, and `set()` must be as small as possible (and consistent, too) for good results. In high-performance applications (more like robotics than a thermostat), the application author will have to consider other factors like delay introduced by preemption of the thread, or even running the entire program on “bare metal” to get consistent results.

As a library author, you cannot control many of the factors of timing. So, don't try — you'll just make a harder-to-use API.